# NodeJS express-validator, validationErrors()

Tags: json, node.js, flash, express

I am needing some help with **express-validator** and **connect-flash** in a simple **NodeJS** application I have

My current code in my usercontroller module.exports.post has req.flash('error', errors) the error messages work and are flashing with connect flash but are just showing [object Object] instead of the actual message, I can do a JSON.stringify(errors) and I get the JSON message for the error, but I want it to display just the msg itself, this is the code:

```
module.exports.postUpdatePassword = (req, res, next) => {
req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 4 characters long').len(4);
req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

const errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
req.flash('error', errors);
return res.redirect('/editaccount');
}
```

and this is what is display currently from the flash if I add JSON.stringify(errors):

```
[{"param":"password","msg":"Password must be at least 4 characters long","value":""}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `req.flash('error', errors[0].msg);`